# Text in the header with memoir

Tags: header-footer, memoir

How do I put text in the header with the memoir class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually Section 7.3 of the [memoir](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) manual is very clear in this point.

Comment: I tried makeoddhead, but it didn't seem to change anything...